# Prolog - matching similar pattern using variable

Tags: list, variables, prolog, pattern-matching

I have a pattern defined as `list1(a,[_,a,_]).` by calling `list1(a,X)`, it will gives out:

```
X = [_G3801, a, _G3807].
```

I need to write a predicate `match(X, List_in, List_out)`, so that by calling it with 
Listin = [[b,a,b],[b,b,a],[a,a,a],[c,c,b]], it can give out all the matched pattern. Something  like this:

```
list1(a,X),match(X,[[b,a,b],[b,b,a],[a,a,a],[c,c,b]], List_out).
```

then it can give:

```
List_out = [[b,a,b],[a,a,a]].
```

I tried `list1(a,X),include(member(X),[[b,a,b],[b,b,a],[a,a,a],[c,c,b]],Y).`
it gives out

```
X = [_G4381, a, _G4387],
Y = [].
```

which it not what I need.
The predicate should be able to generalized since list1(a,X) can be defined arbitrarily,
for example give `list2(a,[_,_,_])`, then

```
list2(a,X),match(X,[[b,a,b],[b,b,a],[a,a,a],[c,c,b]], List_out).
```

should give

```
List_out =[[b,a,b],[b,b,a],[a,a,a],[c,c,b]].
```

(`X` have to be a variable list since it is actually result from other parts of the program , I am just using `list1(a,X)` to demonstrate the problem).

The tricky part is I can not checking element by element, `X` will only unify with only the first match one and miss all the rest. It's more like calling:

```
list1(a,X),member(X,[[b,a,b],[b,b,a],[a,a,a],[c,c,b]]).
X = [b, a, b] ;
X = [a, a, a] ;
false.
```

After find the fist match, it can only backtrack to find a second one.
But how can I put all the backtrack result into one single output list? Can somebody help me?

Comment: Have you tried using the `bagof` predicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems you're doing it more complicated than is due:

```
list1(E, [_,E,_]).
pred1(X) :- list1(a,X),member(X,[[b,a,b],[b,b,a],[a,a,a],[c,c,b]]).
```

will give

```
?- pred1(X).
X = [b, a, b] ;
X = [a, a, a] ;
```

and then you can wrap your queries in findall/3. The 'service predicate' list1/2 it's useless, use ([=](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28%3D%29/2))/2 (that is, unification) - instead:

```
pred1(X) :- X=[_,a,_],member(X,[[b,a,b],[b,b,a],[a,a,a],[c,c,b]]).
```

Prolog still is able to surprise me (specifically, [include](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=include/3)/3). I tried (part of) your code

```
?- include(member(X),[[b,a,b],[b,b,a],[a,a,a],[c,c,b]],Y).
X = b,
Y = [[b, a, b], [b, b, a], [c, c, b]].
```

nice !

Comment: 'findall' and 'bagof' are both useful in my case,"bagof" maybe more suitable. 'list1/2' is just there for me to present the problem. As I mentioned, the pattern of X is arbitrary and is result from other part of the program so that a fix pattern can not be defined in the predicate. But anyway, thanks for your valuable advice.